# How to remove permanently custom view from EventViewer?

Tags: windows-10, event-log, event-viewer

I have created a custom view in Event Viewer. I deleted the custom view from Event Viewer, the custom view disappear, then I launched Event Viewer again but the custom view reappeared.

Windows 10 version is 1803.

[image: Screencast]

Contents of `%ProgramData%\Microsoft\Event Viewer\Views\` is: `ServerRoles` (directory) and `View_0.xml`.

`View_0.xml` contains:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ViewerConfig>
   <QueryConfig>
      <QueryParams>
         <Simple>
            <Channel>System</Channel>
            <EventId>12,13,20,27,42,107</EventId>
            <Source>Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Boot,Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power</Source>
            <RelativeTimeInfo>0</RelativeTimeInfo>
            <BySource>False</BySource>
         </Simple>
      </QueryParams>
      <QueryNode>
         <Name LanguageNeutralValue="State">State</Name>
         <QueryList>
            <Query Id="0" Path="System">
               <Select Path="System">*[System[Provider[@Name='Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Boot' or @Name='Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power'] and (EventID=12 or EventID=13 or EventID=20 or EventID=27 or EventID=42 or EventID=107)]]</Select>
            </Query>
         </QueryList>
      </QueryNode>
   </QueryConfig>
   <ResultsConfig>
      <Columns>
         <Column Name="Level" Type="System.String" Path="Event/System/Level" Visible="">100</Column>
         <Column Name="Keywords" Type="System.String" Path="Event/System/Keywords">70</Column>
         <Column Name="Date and Time" Type="System.DateTime" Path="Event/System/TimeCreated/@SystemTime" Visible="">150</Column>
         <Column Name="Source" Type="System.String" Path="Event/System/Provider/@Name" Visible="">60</Column>
         <Column Name="Event ID" Type="System.UInt32" Path="Event/System/EventID" Visible="">60</Column>
         <Column Name="Task Category" Type="System.String" Path="Event/System/Task" Visible="">60</Column>
         <Column Name="User" Type="System.String" Path="Event/System/Security/@UserID">50</Column>
         <Column Name="Operational Code" Type="System.String" Path="Event/System/Opcode">110</Column>
         <Column Name="Log" Type="System.String" Path="Event/System/Channel">80</Column>
         <Column Name="Computer" Type="System.String" Path="Event/System/Computer">170</Column>
         <Column Name="Process ID" Type="System.UInt32" Path="Event/System/Execution/@ProcessID">70</Column>
         <Column Name="Thread ID" Type="System.UInt32" Path="Event/System/Execution/@ThreadID">70</Column>
         <Column Name="Processor ID" Type="System.UInt32" Path="Event/System/Execution/@ProcessorID">90</Column>
         <Column Name="Session ID" Type="System.UInt32" Path="Event/System/Execution/@SessionID">70</Column>
         <Column Name="Kernel Time" Type="System.UInt32" Path="Event/System/Execution/@KernelTime">80</Column>
         <Column Name="User Time" Type="System.UInt32" Path="Event/System/Execution/@UserTime">70</Column>
         <Column Name="Processor Time" Type="System.UInt32" Path="Event/System/Execution/@ProcessorTime">100</Column>
         <Column Name="Correlation Id" Type="System.Guid" Path="Event/System/Correlation/@ActivityID">85</Column>
         <Column Name="Relative Correlation Id" Type="System.Guid" Path="Event/System/Correlation/@RelatedActivityID">140</Column>
         <Column Name="Event Source Name" Type="System.String" Path="Event/System/Provider/@EventSourceName">140</Column>
      </Columns>
   </ResultsConfig>
</ViewerConfig>
```

I have tried to delete that file, but it does not help. The file was recreated.

Comment: What version of Windows 10 are you using.  Please use the edit function to clarify your question

Comment: Anything under: %ProgramData%\Microsoft\Event Viewer\Views\ to remove?

Comment: @Ramhound question is updated.

Comment: Do you see reference to "State" in View_0.xml?

Comment: @HelpingHand Yes. Should I just delete that file?

Comment: I wouldn't delete it but look to remove the section for the "State".  Maybe Pastebin the contents of your file and link to it.   I'd suggest take a backup of the file before making any changes.

Comment: @HelpingHand I've updated the question.

Comment: What it you remove the: `<QueryNode> to </QueryNode>` section withing the `QueryConfig section`, including these tags and save the file?

Comment: @HelpingHand EventViewer crashes. | The problem is that State is stored in different file in different directory. I need to find a place where the file is referenced from. `View_0.xml` has no file paths inside.

Comment: Maybe running process monitor would reveal it?

Comment: It is crashing all the time: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4508640/event-viewer-may-close-or-you-may-receive-an-error-when-using-custom-v

Answer (score 0):

What I did is just clicked the my custom log (that way selecting it) and hit "delete" on the keyboard.Then click yes when confirmation dialog appears.